# Swift Type Eraser - Create array of Protocols

Tags: swift, enums

I am trying to create a wrapper struct so I can have an array of protocols.
I have watched several videos on type eraser but I can't seem to properly concoct a magic solution.

```
private lazy var properties: [AnyProperty] = [
  AnyProperty(property: shape),
  AnyProperty(property: color),
  AnyProperty(property: number),
  AnyProperty(property: shading)
]

protocol Property {
  static var allValues : [Self] {get}
}

struct AnyProperty<P : Property>:Property {
   private var property : P
   init(property : P){
      self.property = property
   }
   static var allValues: [AnyProperty<P>] {
      get{ return P.allValues as! [AnyProperty<P>] }
   }
}
```

I see one of my main issues is I'm not able to return property.allValues. Possibly my last line of code isn't a proper get conformance. Again, the main goal is to create an array of Properties. `color`, `shape`, `number`, `shading` are all enums conforming to Property protocol.

Thank you I really appreciate the time you have taken to view this. I am struggling with type-erasure.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.7.2 you can use the [`any`](https://forums.swift.org/t/introduction-of-new-keyword-any-for-protocol-conforming-arguments/56266) keyword:

```swift
private var properties: [any Property] = [
  AnyProperty(property: shape),
  AnyProperty(property: color),
  AnyProperty(property: number),
  AnyProperty(property: shading)
]

properties.forEach { p in
    print(type(of: p))
}
```

prints :

```
AnyProperty<Shape>
AnyProperty<Color>
AnyProperty<Number>
AnyProperty<Shading>
```

and you don't have to use `AnyProperty<P>` :

```swift
private var properties: [any Property] = [
    shape,
    color,
    number,
    shading,
]

properties.forEach { p in
    print(type(of: p))
}
```

prints:

```
Shape
Color
Number
Shading
```

And you can use it without loosing type information